# Admin site not show page

Tags: admin, wsgi, django-1.6

I want use Django 1.6 and Python 2.7 in pythonanywhere.com and I have a problem with admin site.

I use [this tutorial](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango)

and when I start [this page](http://daro822.pythonanywhere.com/admin/)

I have

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server.

If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

In Server log i had

```
2014-06-24 17:42:42 Tue Jun 24 17:42:42 2014 - received message 1 from emperor
2014-06-24 17:42:42 ...gracefully killing workers...
2014-06-24 17:42:42 Gracefully killing worker 1 (pid: 11706)...
2014-06-24 17:42:43 worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
2014-06-24 17:42:43 uWSGI: GAME OVER (insert coin)
2014-06-24 17:42:43 chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 1541]
2014-06-24 17:42:43 VACUUM: unix socket /var/sockets/daro822.pythonanywhere.com/socket removed.
2014-06-24 17:42:44 *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.5.1 (64bit) on [Tue Jun 24 17:42:43 2014] ***
2014-06-24 17:42:44 compiled with version: 4.8.1 on 05 June 2014 15:39:26
2014-06-24 17:42:44 os: Linux-3.11.0-22-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 20:47:00 UTC 2014
2014-06-24 17:42:44 nodename: giles-liveweb6
2014-06-24 17:42:44 machine: x86_64
2014-06-24 17:42:44 clock source: unix
2014-06-24 17:42:44 pcre jit disabled
2014-06-24 17:42:44 detected number of CPU cores: 4
2014-06-24 17:42:44 current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
2014-06-24 17:42:44 detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
2014-06-24 17:42:44 using Linux cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpu/user_types/free with mode 700
2014-06-24 17:42:44 assigned process 12031 to cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpu/user_types/free/tasks
2014-06-24 17:42:44 using Linux cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpuacct/users/daro822 with mode 700
2014-06-24 17:42:44 assigned process 12031 to cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpuacct/users/daro822/tasks
2014-06-24 17:42:44 using Linux cgroup /mnt/cgroups/memory/user_types/free with mode 700
2014-06-24 17:42:44 assigned process 12031 to cgroup /mnt/cgroups/memory/user_types/free/tasks
2014-06-24 17:42:44 uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
2014-06-24 17:42:44 chroot() to /mnt/chroots/daro822
2014-06-24 17:42:44 setgid() to 60000
2014-06-24 17:42:44 setuid() to 327191
2014-06-24 17:42:44 limiting number of processes to 15...
2014-06-24 17:42:44 your processes number limit is 15
2014-06-24 17:42:44 your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2014-06-24 17:42:44 detected max file descriptor number: 123456
2014-06-24 17:42:44 building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...
2014-06-24 17:42:44 536 entry found
2014-06-24 17:42:44 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2014-06-24 17:42:44 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2014-06-24 17:42:44 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/daro822.pythonanywhere.com/socket fd 7
2014-06-24 17:42:44 Python version: 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:40:54)  [GCC 4.8.1]
2014-06-24 17:42:44 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2014-06-24 17:42:44 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x23507e0
2014-06-24 17:42:44 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2014-06-24 17:42:44 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2014-06-24 17:42:44 setting request body buffering size to 65536 bytes
2014-06-24 17:42:44 mapped 333952 bytes (326 KB) for 1 cores
2014-06-24 17:42:44 *** Operational MODE: single process ***
2014-06-24 17:42:44 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x23507e0 pid: 12031 (default app)
2014-06-24 17:42:44 *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2014-06-24 17:42:44 spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 12031)
2014-06-24 17:42:44 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 12032, cores: 1)
2014-06-24 17:42:44 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2014-06-24 17:42:45 announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

Comment: `2014-06-24 17:42:45 announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...` Say what!?

Comment: Do you have more than 3 seconds of log...? also the emperor i believe is uwsgi running in emperor mode (runs a bunch of wsgi scripts at the same time from configuration files)

Comment: It,s all log from the day https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4655056/log.doc

Comment: You haven't really followed the tutorial that you listed. The page at http://daro822.pythonanywhere.com/ is still the default PythonAnywhere web app. If you'd followed the tutorial fully, it would be a 404 page from Django or a default Django front page.

Comment: I do this tutorial 2 or 3 times and it's not good

Comment: It's work! Sory I editing wsgi in wrong place.